# DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChange not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownCountry" runat="server"                                         
                  CssClass="form-control form-control-dropdown"                                         
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdownCountry_SelectedIndexChanged"  
                  EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true">
 </asp:DropDownList>

protected void dropdownCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var countryId = Convert.ToInt32(dropdownCountry.SelectedValue);
    var states = from st in model.states
                 where st.CountryId == countryId
                 select st;
    dropdownState.DataValueField = "StateId";
    dropdownState.DataTextField = "State1";
    dropdownState.DataSource = states;
    DataBind();
}
```

I have set both values `EnableViewState="true"` and `AutoPostBack="true"`. My page load event is fired but `dropdownCountry_SelectedIndexChanged` not fired

Comment: try debugging your code and check. Also post your aspx code.

Comment: I have set break point on  dropdownCountry_SelectedIndexChanged but not fired please check  first few lines of above question for aspx code

Comment: Step: 1. Clean your solution, Close your project, close the IIS, 

2. Open the project again, try debugging again and check whether it works or not

Comment: @ShankarKamble it works fine when i copied your code into my project. Event does get fired.... Place a breakpoint within the function and then debug.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: You are trying to populate dropdownState, right? I'd put that into an UpdatePanel and set the trigger to dropdownCountry.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Plz tell where this drop down is placed.What is the container for it?I suggest you to test in a plain web form with just drop down code and see.That way you can identify the probelm in your actual page easily.

Comment: Sorry all of you , Finally found what's wrong with me , I have two form tag in master page of this page which contains dropdown

Answer (score -2):

Use `!Page.IsPostBack` on Page_Load